# How to remove whitespace from a asciz string ARM assembly (without external libraries)

Tags: assembly, arm, whitespace

I'm trying to make a simple command line interface for my raspberry pi 4 using assembly,

I can receive input okay and output to the screen okay the problem is when I make the input size 20 but only put in 10 I get a random addition to my screen

here is the code

```
.data
output: .byte 0
.text
.global _start

_start:
    mov R2,#20 @size of input
    bl read @call read subroutine
    ldr R1,=output @get what was typed
    mov R2,#20 @size of output
    bl write @call write subroutine
    b finish @finish
finish:
    mov R7,#1 @ syscall for exit
    SWI 0 @software interrupt

write:
    MOV R7,#4 @ syscall for output
    MOV R0,#1 @use stdout
    SWI 0

    BX lr

read:
    LDR R1, =output

    MOV R7,#3 @ syscall for input
    MOV R0,#0 @use stdin
    SWI 0
    BX lr
```

the output I get is

hello (the text I typed)

hello (the text getting outputed)

\n\o\o\o\oaeabi\o\o\o\o\o (the random stuff)

here is a picture from putty (the \o and \n cant be seen) [image: image of the code being run over ssh]

here is a picture from cmd
[image: same again but over cmd]

would it be possible the remove all of the characters that the user didn't type in
using above as example I would like the string to only contain hello and remove everything else

some system info:

cpu: broadcomm cortex a72 
architecture: 64-bit based processor
core / thread: 4 / 4 
0s: 32-bit raspbian buster
arm v8

Comment: `read` returns how many bytes were actually read.  (run `strace ./foo` to see).  Use that as the length arg to `write`, instead of dumping the full buffer, including whatever uninitialized garbage was there.  Also, it looks like you didn't pass a buffer pointer to `read`.

Comment: my read function didn't copy correctly so It didnt show up

Comment: it has an extra line of code which is LDR R1,=output

Comment: You've only reserved space for a single byte at `output`. Also, it doesn't look like you're setting up `R1` before the `read` system call.

Comment: I tried using .word .byte .ascii and .asciz all returned the same

Comment: @blankettripod32: If your question doesn't have your actual code, [edit] it to match what you actually ran.  Make sure to copy/paste to avoid errors like this.

Comment: `.word 0` is only 4 bytes.  Use `.space 20` for a 20 byte buffer (preferably in .bss), so you aren't overwriting other data.

Comment: here is the strace on it execve("./boot", ["./boot"], 0xbee40670 /* 25 vars */) = 0
read(0, hello
"hello\n", 20)                  = 6
write(1, "hello\naeabi\0\1\v\0\0\0\6\2\10", 20hello
aeabi    ) = 20
exit(20)                                = ?
+++ exited with 20 +++

Comment: using .space got rid of the \o \v and \n but now I just have plain old white space

Comment: @PeterCordes how would I get the number of bytes read in the program to change the length passed to write

Comment: It's the return value from the first system call like I said.  It's in R0, of course.  The system-call ABI is fairly similar to the function calling convention.

Comment: that fixed the problem thanks